# Adding date in Gregorian Calendar

Tags: java, date

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
public class CalendarMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        int month = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)+1;
        int year = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
        int weekday = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println(month+"/"+dayOfMonth+"/"+year);
        calendar.add(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10);
        System.out.println(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
}
```

I am trying to add 10 days to the current date but am getting a weird problem. It does not seem to be adding correctly.

**Output:**

> 9/18/2014
>
> 5

Comment: `System.out.println(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`? I doubt that's what you intended to do...

Answer (score 3):

```
// Get a calendar which is set to a specified date.
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2014, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);

// Get the current date representation of the calendar.
Date startDate = calendar.getTime();

// Increment the calendar's date by 1 day.
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

// Get the current date representation of the calendar.
Date endDate = calendar.getTime();

System.out.println(startDate);
System.out.println(endDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the last row is wrong, try this:

```
System.out.println(calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
System.out.println(calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

**Output :**

```
9/18/2014
28
```

What you were doing in your code is printing the integer code of `GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` final variable, Which will remain **5**, no matter what you have added in `calendar`. You were needed to use `calendar.get(...)` function to get the date of month of this calendar.